# ReactDOM.render into a <div> does not immediately produce HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm using React v16.7 and I'm trying to inject React components into a third party JS library (namely, Highcharts) that requires me to return HTML from a function. Here's what I'm doing right now:

```
function tooltipFormatter(dataPoint) {
    // ... Calculate props according to the dataPoint here ...
    const mountPoint = document.createElement('div');
    ReactDOM.render(<Tooltip {...tooltipProps} />, mountPoint);
    return mountPoint.innerHTML;
}
```

And I pass this function in a configuration object, like so:

```
const config = {
    ...,
    tooltip: {
        ...,
        formatter() {
            return tooltipFormatter(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that `mountPoint.innerHTML` is empty. I found that `ReactDOM.render()` sometimes works [asynchronously](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render):

> `ReactDOM.render()` currently returns a reference to the root `ReactComponent` instance. However, using this return value is legacy and should be avoided because future versions of React may render components asynchronously in some cases. If you need a reference to the root `ReactComponent` instance, the preferred solution is to attach a [callback ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute) to the root element.

While debugging, I did this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Tooltip {...tooltipProps} />, mountPoint, () => {
    console.log(mountPoint.innerHTML); // non-empty 
});
console.log(mountPoint.innerHTML);  // empty
return mountPoint.innerHTML;
```

How can I coerce `ReactDOM.render()` into working in a synchronous context? The puzzling thing is that `return mountPoint.innerHTML` has worked in the rest of our application, but it seems that this case is the only place `ReactDOM.render()` has chosen to render the contents asynchronously.

Comment: I have found some typos where you have two `return`s in your first code block.

Comment: Is it possible to convert `tooltipFormatter` into an async method? Then you can wrap `React.DOM.render`, which accepts a callback in a function that returns a promise, which you can `await` inside `tooltipFormatter`.

Comment: @Huy Thank you, I fixed it.

Comment: @SungM.Kim I doubt that, since Highcharts is the caller of `config.tooltip.formatter` and that context is probably not an `async` context.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using

```
return ReactDOM.renderToStaticMarkup(<Tooltip {...props} />);
```

since my components are not interactive (no event listeners, and my components aren't stateful).

Although I'm willing to bet [Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) can probably solve the problem, I couldn't get the `ref` of the DOM node that Highcharts renders a tooltip or legend label into.